# handle Apache camel's PredicateValidationException when using validate

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm using springboot `camel-validator-starter` to validate the query param of the incoming request. The library is throwing `PredicateValidationException` with 500 as the status code. I want to handle this exception in such a way that it throws a proper custom exception. According to [camel validate document](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/eips/validate-eip.html) I can create a `PredicateExceptionFactory` bean to handle the exception. However, its unclear how create this bean and there is no example of that. would be highly appreciated if someone could help me with that.

here is the code:

```
rest("/").description(description)
                .id(routeId)
                .get(endpoint)
                .produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto)
                .type(responseClazz)
                .enableCORS(true)
                .route()
                .onException(CustomValidationFailed.class)
                .handled(true)
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST))
                .setBody(constant("offerId should be provided"))
                .end()
                .validate(header("offerId").isNotNull())
                .end()
                .endRest()
                .to(routeTechnicalId);
```

and here is the thrown exception:

```
org.apache.camel.support.processor.PredicateValidationException: Validation failed for Predicate[header(offerId) is not null]. Exchange[]
    at org.apache.camel.support.processor.PredicateValidatingProcessor.process(PredicateValidatingProcessor.java:70)
    at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:66)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryTask.doRun(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:812)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:720)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:187)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:64)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:184)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:399)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.process(DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorSupport.process(AsyncProcessorSupport.java:41)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.doExecute(CamelServlet.java:319)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.doService(CamelServlet.java:214)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.service(CamelServlet.java:130)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)
```

Answer (score 0):

You implement this interface in a class, and then depending on what runtime you use (spring boot, quarkus or something else) then that bean instance can either be auto created by those runtimes. And if not, you need to manually register the bean instance to Apache Camel.